# Internal partitions on read-only

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, hard-drive

I'm a complete beginner and I know this question has been asked to death, but for me no solutions I could find worked so I'm just asking here. 
I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS and have a 1TB HDD and a 256GB SSD. Both Windows and Ubuntu are installed on the SSD, I use the HDD and a 80GB partition on the SSD for shared files between the systems.

Windows can write files just fine, but ubuntu can't. The partitions I'm trying to use are `sda1` and `sdb5` and both are `ntfs`.

`lsblk -l` (+ uuid and filesystem)

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE FSTYPE   UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0  65.9M  1 loop squashfs                                      /snap/discord/93
loop1    7:1    0 140.7M  1 loop squashfs                                      /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/74
loop2    7:2    0  14.5M  1 loop squashfs                                      /snap/gnome-logs/45
loop3    7:3    0    13M  1 loop squashfs                                      /snap/gnome-characters/139
loop4    7:4    0   2.3M  1 loop squashfs                                      /snap/gnome-calculator/260
loop5    7:5    0    91M  1 loop squashfs                                      /snap/core/6350
loop6    7:6    0 180.2M  1 loop squashfs                                      /snap/spotify/35
loop7    7:7    0  53.7M  1 loop squashfs                                      /snap/core18/970
loop8    7:8    0 124.2M  1 loop squashfs                                      /snap/code/9
loop9    7:9    0  34.6M  1 loop squashfs                                      /snap/gtk-common-themes/818
loop10   7:10   0   3.7M  1 loop squashfs                                      /snap/gnome-system-monitor/57
loop11   7:11   0 155.4M  1 loop squashfs                                      /snap/chromium/750
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk                                               
└─sda1   8:1    0 931.5G  0 part ntfs     7ECE4525CE44D755                     /media/kris/HDD
sdb      8:16   0 238.5G  0 disk                                               
├─sdb1   8:17   0   529M  0 part ntfs     8C487ED2487EBA92                     
├─sdb2   8:18   0   100M  0 part vfat     5A7F-B493                            /boot/efi
├─sdb3   8:19   0    16M  0 part                                               
├─sdb4   8:20   0    60G  0 part ntfs     8EBE83E3BE83C1E7                     
├─sdb5   8:21   0    80G  0 part ntfs     C6FE783EFE7828B7                     /media/kris/Shared SSD
└─sdb6   8:22   0  97.9G  0 part ext4     119da87b-4479-436b-877c-d5dfe604d656 /
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Not sure what the loops are, but I don't think they're necessary so I'll exclude them from now on.

`sudo fdisk -l`

```
Device     Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1   2048 1953523711 1953521664 931.5G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb1       2048   1085439   1083392  529M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sdb2    1085440   1290239    204800  100M EFI System
/dev/sdb3    1290240   1323007     32768   16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sdb4    1323008 127152127 125829120   60G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb5  127152128 294924287 167772160   80G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb6  294924288 500117503 205193216 97.9G Linux filesystem
```

`/etc/fstab`

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>

#Entry for /dev/sdb6 :
UUID=119da87b-4479-436b-877c-d5dfe604d656   /   ext4    errors=remount-ro   0   1
#Entry for /dev/sdb2 :
UUID=5A7F-B493  /boot/efi   vfat    umask=0077  0   1
#Entry for /dev/sda1 :
UUID=7ECE4525CE44D755   /media/kris/HDD ntfs-3g defaults,locale=en_GB.UTF-8 0   0
#Entry for /dev/sdb5 :
UUID=C6FE783EFE7828B7   /media/kris/Shared\040SSD   ntfs-3g defaults,locale=en_GB.UTF-8 0   0
/swapfile   none    swap    sw  0   0
```

First I tried using

```
sudo chgrp adm /media/kris/HDD
sudo chmod g+w /media/kris/HDD
```

Didn't work. Next I installed `ntfs-3g` and `ntfs-config` and ran ntfs-config, didn't help.

Lastly I disabled `fast boot` in my bios and started and shutdown windows and ubuntu a couple of times for good measure, didn't work.

I think it has to do something with `fdisk` listing it as `Windows basic data`. But I couldn't find a way to change it and some people said it's a cosmetic thing.

Ideally I'd like to have shared folders like downloads and google drive for both OS's.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out setting `fast boot` to disabled in bios isn't enough, I had to change the power button settings on windows too.